# Condensation drops

Tags: texturing, particles, light

I need add drops water to my plastic bottle.

I use for my bottle Glossy material and for my drops glass material.

[image]

I look for this aspect:

[image]

Comment: Well, the bottle material in reality is not only glossy and water drops are not only glass.. Some more complicated materials and lighting setup will be needed, you could start here - https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-rainy-window/